# Accordion Panel isn't opening on my javascript page that also features a map loaded with d3

Tags: javascript, accordion

My accordion panels aren't working. I'm basically using the exact example from w3 with a few stylistic modifications except I'm splitting the components up into their various pages, eg the html is going on my index page, the javascript is on my .js and the css on .css. My accordion appears on my page but none of the panels will open. I figure maybe I'm placing the .js wrong. Any help would be appreciated and here's the link to my full project if you need to check out the details in more depth (https://github.com/Sharitau/website/tree/main/Portfolio/GovernanceFinal)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I turn your code into a runnable snippet (see the edit history), everything works.

Comment: That’s my problem too. I know the code itself works but it isnt working in my project and I’m not sure why. I thought maybe it has to do with the actual placement on my .js page or something

Comment: Make sure your .js file is the last one you import

Comment: Thanks again! That actually was the solution I was just missing something in my .css file!